# Scheduled tasks in Windows Server 2016 don't run after being disabled then enabled

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-task-scheduler

I am having a problem with the Task Scheduler on Windows Server 2016 not running repetitive tasks after they are disabled and re-enabled.

I create a task with a “Triggers->Start” of five minutes in the future and set the task to run every five minutes. The “Settings->Run task as soon as possible after scheduled start is missed” option is checked.

Everything works fine – task runs at the scheduled Start time and then runs every five minutes.

Disable the task and wait more than five minutes.

Enable the task, it does not run again.

The Next Run time continues to update every five minutes but the task does  not run and the Last Run Time is never updated.

There are no entries in the Task History once the task is re-enabled and no events in the Windows event logs.

Comment: Maybe research over on https://superuser.com/ or similar? Not really on topic for SO.

Comment: UPDATE: when the time rolls around the next day to the scheduled time the tasks starts running again but this is not the desired behavior as it caused a potentially long delay from when the task is re-enabled to when it starts running again.

Comment: I will check there - did not realize this was not an appropriate topic - if not too much trouble can you enlighten me as to why? TIA

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Running task scheduler on a server is not a programming matter. That is why the question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The task was set to run every day and repeat either indefinitely or daily. I changed it to Run Once and repeat indefinitely and resumes running on the schedule once enabled again.

I believe why this works is that the scheduler shows that the task will "After triggered run every x minutes indefinately" even when the task is disabled.

The task stays in the "has been triggered" state when disabled and and so resumes running once enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a bit more specific of an answer to this conundrum. The short version is that you need to set tasks as "One time" rather than "Daily" if you want them to resume one interval after being re-enabled. If they are set up as "Daily" they will ignore the Repeat interval until the Start time comes around again.

The more complete answer is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77614275/141508