# Scheduled Task - Trigger doesn't work after disable/enable with remote PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2019

I created a Scheduled Task which gets triggered every day every 5 minutes. The task itself works fine.

In our deployment process I stop and disable the task with remote PowerShell from our build server on the target server. We create a backup and copy the new version of our application. After that the scheduled task gets enabled again with remote PowerShell.

After the deployment the scheduled task doesn't get triggered anymore. When I stop and disabled the task manually on the server, copy and paste the new version and then enable again - the trigger works just fine.

Here's a screenshot of the trigger configuration:
[image: Scheduled Task - trigger]

And here's the remote PowerShell command:

```
#doing init stuff

Write-Host "Stop and disable Scheduled Task"
Stop-ScheduledTask -TaskName "\path\task-name"
Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "\path\task-name"

#doing deployment stuff

Write-Host "Enable Scheduled Task"
Enable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "\path\task-name"
```

Notes - OS: Windows Server 2019

Comment: Interestingly enough, I'm looking at something similar at the minute. I don't know what is causing your problem but I have noticed differences between how the scheduled task commands work on 2012 servers versus the later servers. Maybe there's something there. Alternatively, what if you don't stop and disable the task at all. The currently running process will run anyway and when the task next runs, it will be running the newly deployed code.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. AFAIK if I dont stop the task, the deployment process runs into an error if the application is still running. But I will give it a try and let you know how if it works.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear the results of this @skuami. I have found through testing that the processes triggered by the scheduled tasks continue even after the scheduled task is updated. But I've only tested that on Windows Server 2012 R2 as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

This highlights the difference in behavior between a “Daily” task and a “One time” task. This is a bit counterintuitive, but if you want to be able to disable a task, then have it start firing automatically again right after you re-enable it, you need to make it a “One time” task rather than “Daily.”

Here is how they look in the task list (deliberately named to highlight the schedule differences):

[image: List of tasks]

When a Daily task is disabled and re-enabled, it will resume at its Start time (so, later that day or the next day):

[image: Daily task]

If a One time task is disabled and re-enabled, it will resume as soon as one more repeat interval elapses, relative to its Start time.

[image: One time task]